# How to draw a dividing line in the title page?

Tags: titles

Consider the following *metropolis* `beamer` theme(available at https://github.com/matze/mtheme). Now, the title-page of metropolis looks like so:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}

\title{Metropolis}
\subtitle{A modern beamer theme}
\date{\today}
\author{Matthias Vogelgesang}
\institute{Center for modern beamer themes}
 \titlegraphic{\hfill\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{tex1}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image: beamer titlepage]

Now, consider the following titlepage from the *mimosis* thesis template(available at https://github.com/Submanifold/latex-mimosis).

```
    \begin{titlepage}
  \vspace*{5cm}
  \makeatletter
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{tex1}
  \end{figure}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{Huge}
      \@title
    \end{Huge}\\[1cm]
    %
    \begin{Large}
      \@subtitle
    \end{Large}\\[2cm]
    %
    \@author
    %
    \vfill
    A document submitted in partial fulfillment
    of the requirements for the degree of\\
    \emph{Technical Report}\\
    at\\
    \textsc{Miskatonic University}
  \end{center}
  \makeatother
\end{titlepage}

\newpage
\null
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
```

This looks like:

[image]

I want a dividing line just before the author name in the mimosis title page similar to the one present in the metropolis beamer title page.

How to get that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\rule{width}{height}` for this. [Full documentation here.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Rules_and_Struts)

So in your example add this after the \@author:

```
\rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}
```

In case you don't want the line directly after the author, but rather equally far away from author and the bottom message. Then add filling using `\vfill`:

```
\vfill
\rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}
\vfill
```